# how to process variable numbers of parameters for jersey post requests

Tags: http, rest, post, jersey

I've got a Jersey REST server that responds to post requests like so:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String postHtml() {
```

I don't know ahead of time the names of all the parameters that might be sent to me.  With a GET request I handle this like:

```
@Context
private UriInfo context;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getHtml() {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = context.getQueryParameters();
```

how can I do a similar thing with a POST request.  I simply want to get all the parameters supplied in the post and I'll work with them in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can do:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String postHtml(MultivaluedMap<String, String> inFormParams) {
```

If all your parameters are String type, which mine are.  It would be good to know what to do if you have non-String parameters.